# SignalR Core and streaming from server using RX Subject

Tags: rxjs, system.reactive, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I've been search high and low, but there's just too little information out there covering this particular topic.

This is part of my server side SignalR Hub:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{ 
  private ReplaySubject<string> _stream = new ReplaySubject<string>();

  public IObservable<string> Stream()
  {
     return _stream.AsObservable();
  }

  public void TriggerTest()
  {
     return _stream.OnNext("message");
  }
}
```

I successfully connect to the hub and are able to invoke the TriggerTest() method on the server.

The following code on the client, however, is never triggered when _stream receives a new message on the server:

```
this.socket.stream('Stream').subscribe({
        next: (value) => {
            console.log('stream response:');
            console.log(value);
        },
        error: (err) => {
            console.warn(err);
        },
        complete: () => {
            console.log('stream completed');
        }
    });
```

I assume the problem lies on the server, more precisely on the Observable / Subject part, but couldn't find any guidance out there. Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Hubs are transient, so for every Hub invocation a new Hub is created and in your example a new `ReplaySubject<string>` is created. So when `Stream()` is first called the client gets the observable from that hub invocation, but the next hub invocation for `TriggerTest` will have a new stream because the hub will be newly instantiated.

Comment: Oh, right! Thanks for pointing that out! Surely the reason for this!

Comment: Was it the reason? Can you share the new code?

Comment: Yes, that was the reason. The service instantiation where you keep the Subject, must be done in an override of Hub.OnConnectedAsync(). Keep track of the various service instantiations in a static variable could be an option: private static IDictionary<int connectionId, SomeService service>.

When you need to refernce SomeService.YourSubject, you request the object from your IDictionary, based on the connectionId of current user.

There is also a Hub.OnDisconnectedAsync method, where you want to remove the Service instance in your static dictionary.